# Cannot locate "php-phalcon" package in APT, after cURL'ing the .deb file

Tags: debian, apt, php, curl

In Debian 10, I follow the instructions [here](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/installation) to a tee, I cURL the DEB file, then I enter `apt install php-phalcon` or `php7.0-phalcon`. Neither work! I don't know what's wrong It says:

> Unable to locate package php-phalcon
>
> Unable to locate package by glob
>
> php7.0-phalcon Unable to locate package by regex php7.0-phalcon

What could be wrong? I looked at some tutorials, and they say I don't even need to fetch the package with cURL! What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you “cURLing” the DEB file? That’s not what the instructions say you should be doing...

Comment: Could you try with `apt install php7.3-phalcon`? After `apt update`...

Comment: So, what happened when you ran `curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`?

Comment: I could see no reference to a `.deb` file in the posted instructions.  The script  referenced in the instructions should have been downloaded with `curl` and executed with `sudo bash`.  This should have set up a third party PPA, which you should then be able to run `apt-get update && apt-get install php7.0-phalcon`.  Please show the output you got when you executed the downloaded script for further diagnosis.  The output of `apt-get update` may also be interesting.

Comment: @StephenKitt This worked!

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are outdated. On Debian 10, after adding the repository and running `apt update`, you need to run

```
apt install php7.3-phalcon
```

to install the package.